# Combo box - typing selection then clicking out of focus - doesn't select the typed item

Tags: delphi, combobox, focus, delphi-xe2

I'm having an issue with the combo box. I have an event handler for `OnClick` which refreshes data based on what item was selected. The problem is when this scenario occurs:

1. Drop-down the combo box to list the various options
2. Type on the keyboard to find a matching item
3. Combo box changes this selection and calls the `OnClick` event
4. My screen refreshes due to this selection / event
5. Click somewhere outside of the combo box to take the focus away from it
6. Combo box goes back to the previous selection, even though `OnClick` was already called
7. Even though Combo box changed back to prior selection, `OnClick` isn't called again
8. After this, Combo Box shows different value than what my data actually represents

So when you open a combo box, and type a few letters on the keyboard to find the item in the drop-down list, `OnClick` is fired which refreshes my screen. But when you click somewhere outside the combo box (thus taking the focus away from it), the combo box changes back to whatever value was previously selected, instead of what I had typed. And at the same time, the `OnClick` event isn't fired, so the combo box shows the incorrect value compared to what I had loaded on the screen.

How do I make the combo box stay on the selected item in this scenario of typing the item on the keyboard?

Comment: Testing `DroppedDown` and if it is dropped down not refreshing the screen would work?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Sorry, I didn't understand what you asked.

Comment: In the OnClick event, test for the DroppedDown of ComboBox, if it is false, don't refresh the screen.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try that

Comment: It doesn't help, if you can remove the accept I can delete the answer. Drop down the list, use arrows to change item, press enter. Synch lost..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Wow, you're right, there's more issues than I had anticipated.

Comment: So the real issue is really based on how the combo box reacts to keyboard events as opposed to mouse events. I mean, it appears the control treats Mouse events as permanent, whereas Keyboard events are temporary.

Comment: What if someone genuinely wants to "cancel" their selection by pressing escape or moving focus off once they've started to type something?  Would that cause issue if you've changed or loaded data?

Comment: @Jerry - Not neat but you might need to use 'OnCloseUp' to re-synchronize if item index does not match.

Comment: @Jason The issue is that `OnClick` was already called during the temporary selection, but isn't called again when the control reverts back to its prior selection

Comment: So I guess the ultimate question is, when a user uses their keyboard to select one of the items in this drop-down, how do I guarantee that selection will be the one when the control is closed-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, I deal with this using the `OnCloseUp` event. Well, in fact I'm using a sub-classed combo for my drop-down lists and they override both the `Change` and `CloseUp` methods:

```
procedure TMyDropDownList.Change;
begin
  RespondToChange;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyDropDownList.CloseUp;
begin
  RespondToChange;
  inherited;
end;
```

The `RespondToChange` method reacts to the new `ItemIndex` value. If it is expensive to react to every single change whilst the combo is dropped down, then you might consider omitting the call to `RespondToChange` from the `Change` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OnExit to make the entry with the keyboard jive with the Index on the ComboBox; where VarS is assigned OnChange and is the answer you would like to keep:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Windows keyboard select bug, force use of selected }
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf(VarS);
end;
```

I would call this a bug in the ComboBox design.