# How to prevent keyboard input without Enter from changing TComboBox selection in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-2010, vcl

A TComboBox behaves differently for mouse and keyboard input. If an item is highlighted using the mouse, it only becomes selected when clicked. However, when highlighted using the keyboard, using the arrow keys or by entering the first letter of the item, the selected item changes instantly.

How do I (cleanly) change the behavior of keyboard input to be more like mouse input? That is, an item becomes only the selected item when Enter is pressed (a "click").

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968911/combo-box-typing-selection-then-clicking-out-of-focus-doesnt-select-the-typ

Comment: > *"How do I (cleanly) ..."* - My guess: you can't.

Comment: That is simply how ComboBox controls work. That behavior is controlled by the OS, not the VCL.

Comment: The strategy in the question Sertac links to is to let the selection change, but only react to any change when the list closes up.